# New Decoder Returned -1 When trying to run PocketSphinx on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pocketsphinx

I am trying to get pocketsphinx to work on my raspberrypi 3. I have successfully installed it on my rpi but now it wont run correctly. I am using the example code they have for the python module on github but whenever I try to run it I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/pi/VoiceTesting/SphinxTest.py", line 14, in <module>
decoder = Decoder(config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.py", line 228, in __init__
this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

I have done some googling but I wasnt able to find a solution.
[here](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/blob/master/example.py) is a link to the example code on the pocketsphinx github. I havent edited any of it I just copied and pasted it.

Comment: You need to provide full output log, it contains the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pocketsphinx decoder initialization returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941443/pocketsphinx-decoder-initialization-returns-1)

Comment: Most likely the path the model is wrong, you need to specify an absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

This is in reference to the [link](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/blob/master/example.py) you have given in the question description.

I had a similar problem which was due to the fact that 'pocketsphinx' library do not have the files **en-us.lm.bin** and **cmudict-en-us.dict** by default.

It was solved by **downloading the files** and pasting them to correct location and **giving the correct path**:

P.S.: Make sure your PocketSphinx is up-to-date. You can install/update it by executing `pip install pocketsphinx` on terminal.

Detailed steps are given below:

**STEP-1:** Giving the correct path

Get the MODELDIR by:

```
MODELDIR= get_model_path()
```

**STEP-2:** Download the files en-us.lm.bin and cmudict-en-us.dict

Download '**en-us.lm.bin**' file from:
https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/tree/master/sphinx4-data/src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us

Download '**cmudict-en-us.dict**' file from: https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-data/src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict

**STEP-3:** Pasting the files to correct location.

Paste the downloaded files to the directory given by: `(MODELDIR + '/en-us/')`

It should be something like this: C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\model\en-us

**STEP-4:** Modifying the code

The [link](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/blob/master/example.py) you have given has the following code:

```
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
decoder = Decoder(config)
```

Make sure the directory `MODELDIR + 'en-us/en-us'` actually exists.

In my case, the directory was just till `MODELDIR + '/en-us'`.

If this is the case, modify the above code with correct directory:

```
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
decoder = Decoder(config)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: you rocks :) i got this answers from github error :) thanks for answering

Comment: @Ashu I'm glad to hear that. Pls upvote my answer if it was of any help :)