# Pocketsphinx new_Decoder runtime error

Tags: python, speech, pocketsphinx

I'm facing error in pocketsphinx code. I have both pocketsphinx and sphinxbase installed. And I also have built both of these packages with Visual Studio. Here is the code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

from os import environ, path

from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "../../../model"
DATADIR = "../../../test/data"

config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
decoder = Decoder(config)

stream = open(path.join(DATADIR, 'goforward.raw'), 'rb')
#stream = open('10001-90210-01803.wav', 'rb')

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                print ('Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr)
                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

And here is the error:

```
this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pocketsphinx decoder initialization returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941443/pocketsphinx-decoder-initialization-returns-1)

Comment: You can remove the line `config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')` to get more detailed error message. Your error is that MODELDIR does not point to the model folder, you can use absolute path if you are not sure about relative path.

Comment: Didn't work for me man. Tried both solutions. Any other suggestions?